# Throw error on missing imports (JSX/Webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

We have a simple setup of Webpack 4 / Babel 7 in a React app.

I would expect if an import is missing in one of the JSX files - Webpack would kill the build
but we came across cases, for example:

```
export default class SomeClass extends Component {
   render() {
      return (<Button>click</Button>)
   }
```

Where the build does not give us indication that something is wrong (just the built-in es-list in IntelliJ)

Is there some configuration in Webpack that can prevent this?

Comment: I don't think that would really fall under the responsibility of Webpack. However, you could probably add an eslint rule and run eslint in Webpack.

Comment: @BrianThompson while i agree it should not fall under webpack, I was sure there's more to it, perhaps Babel.
It seems like it's a necessary part as the JSX undergoes parsing and traspilation anyway - it makes sense it will be 'tested' on that level and not the linter